# angular http service call unit test with params

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have this service call that I am trying to test

> ```
> get(): Observable<Country[]> {
> const config = { params: new HttpParams().set('pagesize', '300') };
> return this.http
>   .get<any>(`${api_url}countries`, config)
>   .pipe(map(response => (response.data as Country[]))); }
> ```

and this is the test:

```
describe('CountriesService Tests', () => {

let countriesService: CountriesService;
let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

let countries: Country[] = [
    { Country: 'ALBANIA', CountryCode: 'AL', ReportingCountryCode: 'ALB' },
    { Country: 'Canada', CountryCode: 'CA', ReportingCountryCode: 'CND' }];
beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [CountriesService]
    });
    countriesService = TestBed.get(CountriesService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
});
afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
});

it('should return all countries', () => {
    countriesService.get().subscribe((data: Country[]) => {
        expect(data).toBe(countries);
    });
    const url = ({ const: environment.url + 'countries', params: {'pagesize': '300'}});

    let countriesRequest: TestRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(url.const + url.params);

    expect(countriesRequest.request.method).toEqual('GET');

    countriesRequest.flush(countries);
})});
```

I am getting this error: Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: /api/publicdata/countries[object Object]", found none.
the issue us on the params being passed into the call, and I am not sure how to add them. Can you please assist.

Comment: It may be a typo, but the service method is get() but you don’t actually call that specific method in the test, you call getCountries() instead. Also yes you can’t insert an object into a string like that. Use template strings or string concatenation to extract the specific properties you expect. `+ '?pagesize' + params.pagesize` or similar. Match it to what the running application turns the url into.

Comment: It was a typo Thanks though

Comment: Using `expectOne` with GET params is a pain. I find it easier to use the `matchFn` overload of `expectOne` (https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController). It receives the `HttpRequest` object, so you can easily compare the base url and parameter values

Comment: example please, I can't  see the matchFn function, Only match

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if OP fixed it or not!

```
expectOne(url.const + url.params) // Wrong
expectOne(url.const + '?param1=value') // should be that
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are expecting the http call after it is made, try the below test case

```
    it('should return all countries', () => {

    const url = ({ const: environment.url + 'countries', params: {'pagesize': '300'}});

    let countriesRequest: TestRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(url.const + url.params);

    countriesService.getCountries().subscribe((data: Country[]) => {
            expect(data).toBe(countries);
        });

    expect(countriesRequest.request.method).toEqual('GET');

    countriesRequest.flush(countries);
})});
```

Comment: Still the same error. It is something to do with adding parameters into a service call. I I remove the params it works OK but as our back end can do all sorts of filtering by adding parameters to the call I need to ensure that call is as it is supposed t be

Comment: you can probably remove the params, since you are only trying to expect if the http call. also you should be mocking the http call. Add the below statement also
`countriesRequest.result([country array]`

Answer (score 0):

May be I am late but this below solution will work for u guys

1. Create a `HttpParams` object and `append()` your all query parameters in it.
2. Create  `HttpRequest` object and provide it a proper values.
3. Then call `httpTestingController.expectOne()` as shown in below
4. I used `urlWithParams` to compare urls because it reduce code of checking each
   param object.

```
 it('should return all countries', fakeAsync(() => {

    countriesService.getCountries().subscribe((data: Country[]) => {
            expect(data).toBe(countries);
        });
     // you can create multiple parameters by appending on same object 
    let parameters = new HttpParams().append('pagesize', '30');
     
    // environment is your base url
    const httpReq = new HttpRequest('GET',environment.url, {params:parameters}); 

    let countriesRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne((req:HttpRequest)=>
        req.method === httpReq.method && req.urlWithParams === httpReq.urlWithParams
    );
   
    countriesRequest.flush(countries);
    httpTestingController.verify();
});
```